# Looking for a specific control (sketch included)

Tags: controls, javafx-2

I am looking for a control many of us probably know, but I don't know it's name and don't have a real screenshot by hand, just this sketch:

[image]

In the left box one can select an operation or whatever, which then is moved to the right side. With the up/down arrows on the right, one can move this operation (or whatever kind of meaning the entry has) up or down in the order of execution.

How is this kind of control called? Or is it normally build by developers out of single controls? Is this control available in JavaFX 2? If not, I don't need exactly this control, but a control with the following features:

- User can select multiple operations (duplicates allowed) out of all available operations
- The user can arrange their order of execution

Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use multiple controls to build up your interface.  Use two [ListViews](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) with a [MultipleSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html) for each (or at least the left one) and add a couple of buttons, that copy selected items from one list to the other and another couple of buttons which modify the [position of selected items](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) in the right list view by modifying the view's underlying [item list](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#getItems%28%29).

```
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, that would have been my next step, too :-)